# how to list files of specific permissions using UNIX ls command?

Tags: unix, clearcase

I would like to see all the files recursively in a directory or drive which are not read only.

I would like to do this as i am using the clear case and i would like to check on on the files which are to be added to he source control or view-private files.

even a clear case command would help thanks. For clear  case specific i tried "ls -vob_only" command but not helped or i failed to use it so felt that using UNIX command might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -perm -o=r
```

Comment: -1. Not a ClearCase command. And that would list private files that are read-only, giving the false impression they are managed by ClearCase even though they haven't been committed yet. And that doesn't included hijacked or eclipsed files (which, after being read-write, can also end up read-only if the user change their permissions). This simply doesn't answer what the OP is actually asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -perm
```

for more information check the man page for -perm options.

Answer (score 0):

A committed file in ClearCase is indeed read-only.

If by "not read only" you refer to private files not yet added to a view, you can start by [looking for private files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369697/command-line-to-delete-all-clearcase-view-private-files/369952#369952), based on grep rules on a recursive **[`ls`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm)**

```
cleartool ls -r -nxn
```

That would be safer than the "read only" criteria, since private files can also be read only (even though they are "not checked-in" yet, not yet managed by ClearCase)

The idea behind a recursive `ls` is to display all the rules associated with all the files of your view.

- **No rule** means "private" (whether the file is read-only or not)
- **`Rule: ...\aBranch\LATEST`** means it is committed (and -- incidentally -- read-only)
- **`Rule: CHECKEDOUT`** means it is committed, but being modified (read-write, but nothing prevents the user to make it read-only again without checking it in)
- **`Rule: hijacked/eclipsed`**: committed, but modified without having being checked-out yet (read-write, but again, can be turned read-only without notifying ClearCase)

So you can grep whatever set of files you actually need from that list, based on ClearCase rules (or lack thereof).